# How to add sound to animations in BGE?

Tags: animation, game-engine, audio

I have a sword swing animation and a bullet firing animation. How can I add sound to it using the blender game engine?

Answer (score 1):

You can add sound to your animation by using a sound actuator found in the logic editor. First you need to have the sound file(s) downloaded then you can go to bge's logic editor and add a keyboard sensor, assign a letter to the sensor(this is the letter on your keyboard that you will have to press for the animation and sound to start) connect it to an 'and' controller and then add a sound actuator, click on open and choose the file that you downloaded earlier, also you should have an actuator that starts your animation when triggered, connect the 'and' controller to the sound and animation actuators and it should work.

Since I have never actually used a sound yet and don't know what does every setting do. You should take a look at this https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:AnOrdinaryKitten/Doc:2.6/Manual/Game_Engine/Logic/Actuators/Sound/ and check or try which one you need.

Hope this helps :)
Btw your english is fine.

Comment: thank you...... i have voted it. but due to my low score reputation up vote can not added. It will appear after my 15 reputation points. currently i have found video tutorial on adding sound to specific action same like your answer but with video. thanks again...

Comment: @hardwork no problem I cant upvote either yet.

Comment: @hardwork - you should be able to accept the answer (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Upvote is for the audience. You as requester should accept  one answer. thx